# Plotting latitude on (Mercator projection) SVG representing country map

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude, svg

I want to convert (google sourced) **longitude and latitude** coordinates to **x and y** to place points on a **SVG map**

I can get the longitude converted to X but I can't nail latitude.

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/an3BZ/17/

- red dots = place holders
- green dot = calculated position from longitude/latitude

I have read so much about Mercator projections and other projection system API's I am now completely confused. I also followed Proj4JS library threads but couldn't find an example that was close to my task.

I attempted to emulate @Raphael Wichmann and @betamax [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103924/mercator-longitude-and-latitude-calculations-to-x-and-y-on-a-cropped-map-of-the), unfortunately I got something wrong.

Could someone have a look at my jsfiddle and see if it's an obvious mistake?

The second test **function secondconvert(latitude, longitude)** (bottom of javascript pane) provides me with a reasonably accurate **x coordinate** i.e. if I manually enter the **y coordinate** `b.ylat` change to `265` it covers my left red dot place holder nearly perfectly.

I think I'm close.

**Note:** the longitude/latitude bounds I used for my SVG map are best guesstimates, worked surprisingly well for the longitude calculation.

---

Original SVG from [here.](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9c/Ireland_trad_counties_named.svg)

Comment: Is your solution generic? Would be great if you provide a bit of a write up on how the formula works.

Comment: I assume the  MAP_WIDTH = 400; MAP_HEIGHT = 500; properties are the SVG dimensions. How did you calculate westLong, eastLong etc? Assuming they are mercator coords of the top left and bottom right of the map? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I wrote that code nearly 7 years ago and I'm in the middle of a complex project but if I get an hour at the weekend I'll revisit the solution and see what I can do for you. In the mean time try the working version jsfiddle link below and the link to the the other reference.

Comment: Thanks. I've found a working solution using my own inputs. I don't understand why the math works, but it does. I think that would be the most interested area to comment on.

Comment: Enjoy :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Mathematics_of_the_Mercator_projection

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question was answered by @[acraig5075](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1332041/acraig5075) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11339219).

After correcting my mistake and adjusting southern latitude I get:
Fixed link: http://jsfiddle.net/an3BZ/145/